# c bitwise operation to match description

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm supposed to match the worded descriptions to the bitwise operations. W is one less than the total bits in a's and b's data structure. So if a is 32 bits long W is 31 Here are the worded descriptions:

```
1. One’s complement of a
2. a.
3. a&b.
4. a * 7.
5. a / 4 .
6. (a<0)?1:-1.
```

and here are the bitwise descriptions:

```
a.  ̃( ̃a | (b ˆ (MIN_INT + MAX_INT)))
b. ((aˆb)& ̃b)|( ̃(aˆb)&b)
c. 1+(a<<3)+ ̃a
d. (a<<4)+(a<<2)+(a<<1)
e. ((a<0)?(a+3):a)>>2
f. a ˆ (MIN_INT + MAX_INT)
g.  ̃((a|( ̃a+1))>>W)&1
h.  ̃((a >> W) << 1)
i. a >> 2
```

I have a few of them solved namely:

```
a.  ̃( ̃a | (b ˆ (MIN_INT + MAX_INT))) = a & b
b. ((aˆb)& ̃b)|( ̃(aˆb)&b) = a
c. 1+(a<<3)+ ̃a = 7 * a
d. (a<<4)+(a<<2)+(a<<1) = 16*a + 4*a + 2*a = 22*a
e. e. ((a<0)?(a+3):a)>>2 = (a<0)?(a/4 + 3/4) : a/4 = a/4 + ((a<0)?(3/4:0)
f. a ˆ (MIN_INT + MAX_INT) = ~a
i. a >> 2 = a/4
```

So basically all I need help with are g and h

```
g.  ̃((a|( ̃a+1))>>W)&1
h.  ̃((a >> W) << 1)
```

If you wouldn't mind could you also provide an explanation if you could?

I think this is what is going on with g:

```
g.  ̃((a|( ̃a+1))>>W)&1 = ~((a|(two's complement of a) >>W)&1 
= ~((a|sign of two's complement of a) &1 = ~(-a)&1
```

but this could be 1 or 0 so I don't think I did this right.

and for this one:

```
h.  ̃((a >> W) << 1) = ~((sign of a) << 1) = ~((sign of a)*2)
```

and I don't know where to go from there...

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: What is `W` supposed to be?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm sorry W is one less than the total bits in a's or b's data structure. So if a is 32 bits long W is 31

Comment: for g, you've forgot about the braces. The (a|(twos complement of a)) should be bitshifted by W.

Comment: @Simon I did that on the next line where i did = ~(a|sign of two's complement of a) & 1...any other help?

Comment: Just substitute various valued for `a`. Also, this isn't a programming question.

Comment: @RaymondChen I though c bitwise operators and dealing with data types specifics would throw this under programming.

Comment: Are a and b signed?  If so, then is >> logical shift or arithmetic shift?

Comment: They're signed @jschultz410

Comment: Ah, then that tells you what h is too!

Comment: Many of the results here are implementation defined in C. For example, MIN_INT + MAX_INT may not always be -1, and ~x may not be (1-x).

Comment: @Anonymous That's true, but they were likely told to assume a 2's complement representation of signed integers.

Comment: (c) differs from a*7 (in fact, exhibiting undefined behavior) for MAX_INT/8 < a <= MAX_INT/7 (and a similar range of negative numbers).

Comment: In the context of SO, a programming question is "why isn't my program working" or "how do I write a program that,,," This question is too localized. It is unlikely to be useful to anybody else in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For g, consider that (a|~a) sets all bits to 1, so:

~((a|~a) >> W) & 1
~(all_ones >> W) & 1
~1 & 1
0

The only way adding 1 to `~a` could possibly affect this result is if the addition flipped the most significant bit of `~a` (due to the right shift by W).  That can only happen if `a` is 0 or 2^W.  In the latter case, we will get the same result as above because the top bit of (a|X) will always be set.  However, when `a` is 0 `~a+1` (0's twos complement) is also 0 and the final result of the entire expression will instead be 1.

Therefore, g is 1 when `a` is zero, otherwise it is 0 (i.e. - g is equivalent to the C expression `a == 0`).  That seemingly doesn't match any of your worded descriptions.  Indeed, I don't see how any expression (X & 1) possibly matches any of your worded descriptions.  None of your worded descriptions matches an expression that evaluates to only 0 or 1 (for all values of a, b).

For h, consider that if `a` is negative, then its top most bit is set.  Because `a` is signed, right shifting it 31 positions drags the sign bit across all 32 bits of `a`.  Then left shifting it one position sets the least significant bit to 0.  Complementing that yields 1.  If `a` is non-negative, then its top most bit is 0 and right shifting that 31 positions yields 0.  Left shifting that 1 position still yields 0.  Complementing that yields all bits set, which is the 2's complement rep of -1.  Therefore, h is equivalent to (a < 0 ? 1 : -1) or #6 of your worded descriptions.